# Find the roots of $x^3 -6x^2 +13x -12$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots, cubics

I am trying to find the roots of $$\tag{1} x^3 -6x^2 +13x -12$$ by applying the method outlined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2885274/deriving-the-cubic-formula) (I think this Cardan’s method).

Letting $y= x-2$, we can transform $(1)$ into $$\tag{2} y^3 + y -2=0.$$

It is clear that $1$ is a root of $(2)$, and, from the formula $$u - \frac{h}{u}=1,$$ we get $$\tag{3} u= \frac{3+ \sqrt{21}}{6}.$$

Given that the formula for the other two roots of $(2)$ are $$u\omega -\frac{h\omega^2}{u}, \quad u\omega^2 -\frac{h\omega}{u},$$ we can use $(3)$ and the fact that $\omega=\frac{1}{2}\Big(-1+\sqrt{3}i \Big)$ in order to find them, but this seems an incredibly tedious method.

> **Question:** Is there a more expedient way to evaluate the last two roots of $(2)$?

**Note:** I am aware that you can use the fact that $x=3$ is a root of $(1)$ in order to factorise the equation, but I am trying here to use the Cubic Formula.

Comment: Have you tried Cardan's method ??

Comment: @AnikBhowmick This is Cardan’s method (as I understand it).

Comment: sorry, my bad !!

Comment: hint: $y^3+y-2=0 \iff y^3-y^2+y^2-1+y-1=0$

Comment: There is no better way than Cardano's formulas. In the general case the expression of the roots is lengthy (but not incredibly). If you are lucky to have a simple expression for one of the roots do factorise !

Comment: @YvesDaoust Okay, thanks!

Comment: "Question: Is there a more expedient way to evaluate the last two roots of (2)?" Once you know that $y=1$ solves (2), you know that $x=3$ solves (1) hence the LHS of (1) is $(x-3)P(x)$ where $P$ is quadratic. By identification, $$x^3-6x^2+13x-12=(x-3)(x^2-3x+4)$$ hence you are left with solving $$x^2-3x+4=0$$ which is direct.

Comment: @Did Thanks, but in my note I said I was already aware of this method. I was just hoping for a more expedient way of evaluating $(2)$ by using the roots of unity (which others have said there is not).

Comment: Perhaps you are seeking for the trigonometric method of solution of cubics.

Comment: $x^3+x-2=0$
If you're looking for other method of solving this, goodnews there is

Answer (score 1):

If you get one factor i.e $1$, so we have $y-1$ is a factor of $y^3+y-2$, now on dividing you would get a polynomial of degree $2$ in quotient, from there you can find the roots using quadratic formula. Hope it helps  you.

Answer (score 0):

$$x^3+x-2= 0$$
We can eliminate the $x^1$ by using a quadratic tschirnhausen transformation $y= x^2+mx+n$, to get the cubic in a binomial form
$$(y-(x_{1}^{2}+mx_{1}+n))(y-(x_{2}^{2}+mx_{2}+n))(y-(x_{3}^{2}+mx_{3}+n)) = 0$$
Collect the new variable $y$
$$y^3+(\dots \dots)y^2+(\dots \dots)y+(\dots \dots) = 0$$
Solving for the unknowns $m$, $n$ to eliminate the $y^2$ and $y$ term
$$y^3+(2-3n)y^2+(1-6m+m^2-4n+3n^2)y+(-4-2m-2m^3-n+6mn-m^2n+2n^2-n^3) = 0$$
Therefore
$n= \frac{2}{3}$, $m = \frac{9\pm 2\sqrt{21}}{3}$
Using the negative case, the binomial cubic becomes
$$y^3-\frac{112 \cdot {112-6\sqrt{3\cdot 112}}}{54} = 0$$
$$y^3 = (\frac{2}{3})^3\cdot 7\cdot (112-24\sqrt{21})$$
$$y = \frac{2}{3}\sqrt[3]{7(112-24\sqrt{21})}$$
Don't forget $x^2+mx+n-y = 0$ and check for sign
$$x = -\frac{3}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{21}}{3} \pm \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{47}{3}-4\sqrt{21}+\frac{8}{3}\sqrt[3]{7(112-24\sqrt{21})}}$$
The trigonometric solution is
$$x = 2\sqrt{\frac{-1}{3}} \cos(\frac{1}{3}\arccos(-\sqrt{-27}))$$

EDITED to adjust the type settings