# Find the roots of the cubic below

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$3x^3 + 2x^2 +75x -50 = 0$$
Solve for $x$

I've tried to solve this cubic by factoring, but it doesn't factor. Factoring by grouping doesn't work, and using the factor theorem also doesn't work.
How would one go about finding the root/s in a situation like this? I've plugged the equation into a couple of online calculators, they give the roots, but don't explain how they got their results. I have little experience with cubic equations, and I would like to know how you can solve this particular one.

Comment: By the rational root theorem, there are no rational roots. It is easy to see that the cubic has exactly one real root.

Comment: The roots of this cubic don't have a nice form. Are you sure the question is written correctly? i.e. if it was +50 instead of -50, it would be factorable. Or are you supposed to numerically approximate it using a method such as Newton's Method?

Comment: @ndhanson3 Good catch. I strongly suspect that there is a typo in the question.

Comment: Yes, indeed. With $+50$ we obtain $(x^2 + 25)(3x + 2)$, and this looks exactly like a common result for such an exercise.

Comment: @ndhanson3 No, there is no typo, the only thing being asked is to solve for x, there is no specification as to what method you should use.

Comment: Where is this question coming from?

Comment: See the [Brilliant](https://brilliant.org/wiki/cardano-method/) page on Cardano's method for solving a cubic which includes some nice worked examples. (I don't see the precise method on the Wiki page in the linked answer, anyway.)

Comment: @ndhanson3 It's an independent self study course for grade 12, in preparation for University, in Ontario, CA. I caught a few errors in other equations, this might also be one of them, since everybody else is also pointing out that it's sort of weird.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I will see how I can use this, thanks for linking the answer.

Comment: You can try the Newton - Rapson technique.

Comment: For what it's worth, the only methods that I know of for obtaining the exact value of the roots of a cubic equation are the [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), and Cardano's method, both of which have been discussed by previous comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our trick is to find one real root, the other two can be found by complex number or polynomial division
$$3x^3+2x^2+75x-50 = 0$$
$$x^3+\frac{2}{3}x^2+\frac{75}{3}x-\frac{50}{3} = 0$$
$$x = y -\frac{1}{3}\frac{2}{3}$$
$$(y-\frac{2}{9})^3+\frac{2}{3}(y-\frac{2}{9})^2+25(y-\frac{2}{9})-\frac{50}{3} = 0$$
$$y^3+\frac{671}{27}y-\frac{16184}{729} = 0$$
We would use the Tartaglia's formula here
$$y^3+py+q = 0$$
$$y = \sqrt[3]{ -\frac{q}{2} +\sqrt{ (\frac{p}{3})^3+(\frac{q}{2})^2 } } + \sqrt[3]{ -\frac{q}{2} -\sqrt{ (\frac{p}{3})^3+(\frac{q}{2})^2 } } $$
Applying to get
$$y^3+\frac{671}{27}y-\frac{16184}{729} = 0$$
$$ y = \sqrt[3]{ -\frac{-16184}{2\cdot 729} +\sqrt{ (\frac{671}{3\cdot 27})^3+(\frac{-16184}{2\cdot 729})^2 } } + \sqrt[3]{ -\frac{-16184}{2\cdot 729} -\sqrt{ (\frac{671}{3\cdot 27})^3+(\frac{-16184}{2\cdot 729})^2 } } $$
$$ y = \sqrt[3]{ \frac{8092}{729} +\sqrt{ \frac{1512725}{2187} } } + \sqrt[3]{ \frac{8092}{729} -\sqrt{ \frac{1512725}{2187} } } $$
So the solution to your cubic $3x^3+2x^2+75x-50 = 0$ is
$$ x = -\frac{2}{9} + \sqrt[3]{ \frac{8092}{729} +\sqrt{ \frac{1512725}{2187} } } + \sqrt[3]{ \frac{8092}{729} -\sqrt{ \frac{1512725}{2187} } } $$
For other methods to solve the cubic like trigonometry and tschirnhaus see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2889558/find-the-roots-of-x3-6x2-13x-12/3626761#3626761/)

Comment: Thank you for your effort.